# What's the difference between `String.class` and `new Class[]{String.class}`?

Tags: java, reflection, types, constructor

I'm brand new to Java. I have a question as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(String s){}
}

MyClass MyObject;

Constructor ctor1 = MyObject.class.getConstructor(String.class); // #1
Constructor ctor2 = MyObject.class.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class}); // #2
```

What's the difference between **#1** and **#2**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

The parameter type of [`getConstructor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) is `Class<?>...`, which employs the [*varargs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) syntax, which is syntactic sugar that automatically converts a list of elements of any size (including zero) to an array.

To illustrate, these two calls are equivalent:

```
Constructor ctor1 = MyObject.class.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class); // #1
Constructor ctor2 = MyObject.class.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class}); // #2
```

---

Although I admire your enthusiasm of "looking under the hood" (using reflection), if you are new to java you may consider holding off until you have a firm grasp of the basics before learning how to circumvent them.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)
                              throws NoSuchMethodException,
                                     SecurityException
```

Have a look at defination of `getConstructor()`. It takes **var-args** parameter of type `Class (Class<?> ...)`

In your case, both the calls will eventually invoke the same constructor.

Answer (score 0):

None from a functional point of view.

The getConstructor method has a varargs signature where you can supply a variable number of parameters. Internally Java converts this list of parameters to an array so a signature with varargs is the same as a signature with an array of that type.

Your ctor1 uses the varargs 'version' of the signature while your ctor2 uses the array 'version'.

Answer (score -1):

line `#1` will call first constructor
line `#2` will call second

```
public class MyObject {

  public MyObject(String arg) {
    // ...
  }

  public MyObject(String[] args) {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: No, both will invoke the first constructor.